# out of memory with lattice systhesis engine compiling md5 entity

Tags: vhdl, md5

I'm writing an md5 hash function and ran into an unexpected problem synthesizing the design with Lattice's synthesis engine (LSE). Synthesizing to MachXO2 7000HE if that matters.

I get an "Out of memory" error when I attempt to synthesize this entity that partially calculates the md5 of a single 512 bit input. It stops after a very long time (many minutes) using about 6.6GB of ram.

I suspect I may be doing something really dumb here.

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity md5_block is
port(
    clock: in std_logic;
    reset: in std_logic;
    din: in std_logic_vector(511 downto 0);
    dout: out std_logic_vector(127 downto 0));
end entity md5_block;

architecture behavior of md5_block is
type reg_single is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
type reg_quad is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
type shift_quad is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

constant shift_amount: shift_quad := (
    "00111", "01100", "10001", "10110", "00111", "01100", "10001", "10110", 
    "00111", "01100", "10001", "10110", "00111", "01100", "10001", "10110", 
    "00101", "01001", "01110", "10100", "00101", "01001", "01110", "10100",
    "00101", "01001", "01110", "10100", "00101", "01001", "01110", "10100",
    "00100", "01011", "10000", "10111", "00100", "01011", "10000", "10111",
    "00100", "01011", "10000", "10111", "00100", "01011", "10000", "10111",
    "00110", "01010", "01111", "10101", "00110", "01010", "01111", "10101",
    "00110", "01010", "01111", "10101", "00110", "01010", "01111", "10101");

constant k_data: reg_quad := (
     x"d76aa478", x"e8c7b756", x"242070db", x"c1bdceee", x"f57c0faf", x"4787c62a", x"a8304613", x"fd469501",
     x"698098d8", x"8b44f7af", x"ffff5bb1", x"895cd7be", x"6b901122", x"fd987193", x"a679438e", x"49b40821",
     x"f61e2562", x"c040b340", x"265e5a51", x"e9b6c7aa", x"d62f105d", x"02441453", x"d8a1e681", x"e7d3fbc8",
     x"21e1cde6", x"c33707d6", x"f4d50d87", x"455a14ed", x"a9e3e905", x"fcefa3f8", x"676f02d9", x"8d2a4c8a",
     x"fffa3942", x"8771f681", x"6d9d6122", x"fde5380c", x"a4beea44", x"4bdecfa9", x"f6bb4b60", x"bebfbc70",
     x"289b7ec6", x"eaa127fa", x"d4ef3085", x"04881d05", x"d9d4d039", x"e6db99e5", x"1fa27cf8", x"c4ac5665",
     x"f4292244", x"432aff97", x"ab9423a7", x"fc93a039", x"655b59c3", x"8f0ccc92", x"ffeff47d", x"85845dd1",
     x"6fa87e4f", x"fe2ce6e0", x"a3014314", x"4e0811a1", x"f7537e82", x"bd3af235", x"2ad7d2bb", x"eb86d391" );

signal in_data: reg_single;

signal internal_a: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal internal_b: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal internal_c: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal internal_d: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal message_in: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal result_f: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal result_g: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal result_h: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal result_i: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal used_result: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal pre_add: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal post_add: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal post_shift: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal round_num: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
begin
result_f <= (internal_b and internal_c) or (not internal_b and internal_d);
result_g <= (internal_b and internal_d) or (internal_c and not internal_d);
result_h <= internal_b xor internal_c xor internal_d;
result_i <= internal_c xor (internal_b or not internal_d);

in_data(00) <= din(31 downto 0);
in_data(01) <= din(63 downto 32);
in_data(02) <= din(95 downto 64);
in_data(03) <= din(127 downto 96);
in_data(04) <= din(159 downto 128);
in_data(05) <= din(191 downto 160);
in_data(06) <= din(223 downto 192);
in_data(07) <= din(255 downto 224);
in_data(08) <= din(287 downto 256);
in_data(09) <= din(319 downto 288);
in_data(10) <= din(351 downto 320);
in_data(11) <= din(383 downto 352);
in_data(12) <= din(415 downto 384);
in_data(13) <= din(447 downto 416);
in_data(14) <= din(479 downto 448);
in_data(15) <= din(511 downto 480);
message_in <= in_data(to_integer(unsigned(round_num)));

--64 rounds to calculate 128 bit result
--process 512 bits at a time
--32 bits each round
process (all)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        round_num <= (others => '0');
        dout <= (others => '0');
        post_shift <= (others => '0');
        pre_add <= (others => '0');
        post_add <= (others => '0');
        internal_a <= x"67452301";
        internal_b <= x"efcdab89";
        internal_c <= x"98badcfe";
        internal_d <= x"10325476";
    else            
        case round_num(5 downto 4) is
            when "00" => used_result <= result_f;
            when "01" => used_result <= result_g;
            when "10" => used_result <= result_h;
            when "11" => used_result <= result_i;
            when others => used_result <= result_f;
        end case;
        pre_add <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(used_result) + unsigned(internal_a));
        post_add <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(pre_add) + unsigned(message_in) + unsigned(k_data(to_integer(unsigned(round_num)))));
        case shift_amount(to_integer(unsigned(round_num))) is
            when "00000" => post_shift <= post_add;
            when "00001" => post_shift <= post_add(30 downto 0) & post_add(31);
            when "00010" => post_shift <= post_add(29 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 30);
            when "00011" => post_shift <= post_add(28 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 29);
            when "00100" => post_shift <= post_add(27 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 28);
            when "00101" => post_shift <= post_add(26 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 27);
            when "00110" => post_shift <= post_add(25 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 26);
            when "00111" => post_shift <= post_add(24 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 25);
            when "01000" => post_shift <= post_add(23 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 24);
            when "01001" => post_shift <= post_add(22 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 23);
            when "01010" => post_shift <= post_add(21 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 22);
            when "01011" => post_shift <= post_add(20 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 21);
            when "01100" => post_shift <= post_add(19 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 20);
            when "01101" => post_shift <= post_add(18 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 19);
            when "01110" => post_shift <= post_add(17 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 18);
            when "01111" => post_shift <= post_add(16 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 17);
            when "10000" => post_shift <= post_add(15 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 16);
            when "10001" => post_shift <= post_add(14 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 15);
            when "10010" => post_shift <= post_add(13 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 14);
            when "10011" => post_shift <= post_add(12 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 13);
            when "10100" => post_shift <= post_add(11 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 12);
            when "10101" => post_shift <= post_add(10 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 11);
            when "10110" => post_shift <= post_add(09 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 10);
            when "10111" => post_shift <= post_add(08 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 09);
            when "11000" => post_shift <= post_add(07 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 08);
            when "11001" => post_shift <= post_add(06 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 07);
            when "11010" => post_shift <= post_add(05 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 06);
            when "11011" => post_shift <= post_add(04 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 05);
            when "11100" => post_shift <= post_add(03 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 04);
            when "11101" => post_shift <= post_add(02 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 03);
            when "11110" => post_shift <= post_add(01 downto 0) & post_add(31 downto 02);
            when "11111" => post_shift <= post_add(0) & post_add(31 downto 01);
            when others => post_shift <= post_add;
        end case;
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            round_num <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(round_num) + "00001");
            internal_d <= internal_c;
                internal_c <= internal_b;
                internal_a <= internal_d;
                internal_b <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(post_shift) + unsigned(internal_b));
                dout <= result_f & result_g & result_h & result_i;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavior;
```

Comment: Hmm, Xilinx Vivado elaborated your code in 20 seconds... It can be a lattice synthesis thing. You code is VHDL-2008, so maybe lattice does not properly support that? p.s. there are many things in your code that could have been written WAY easier. Using integers etc. But if it works, it works...

Comment: Thanks for the info on xilinx vivaldo working. I kind of figured there were more effective ways for coding this. I'll get to those modifications in time.